# Portable Headphone Amp Power Supply 18V MCP73871 TPS61178 TPS7A470

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, headphones, portable

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to diyaudio, amplifiers, power supplies, schematics, PCB design and everything that this forum touches on (read: noob), so I urge you to be patient with me - I am eager to learn though.

Anyway, on to the point: Recently I came across @xrk971 thread [Hakuin SE Class A HP Amp](https://www.diyaudio.com/forums/headphone-systems/345851-hakuin-se-class-hp-amp.html) which got me interested into building my own amp (PCB design and everything).

But, since X hasn't opened source his power supply schematic I decided to tackle that on my own (without some extras he implemented). Basically what I tried to do is: Battery Charger --> Boost Converter --> LDO.

Spent last few days reading through data sheets and reference designs and this is what I came up with. I would greatly appreciate if you could fact check the schematic and suggest things I should do (things that I probably missed).

I plan to use Samsung's EB-BJ710CBE battery (if possible).

Data Sheets:

[MCP73871](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf), [TPS61178](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61178.pdf?ts=1597960365376&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DTPS61178RNWR), [TPS7A470](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7a47.pdf?ts=1597960445929&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

[image: Portable Headphone Amp Power Supply Schematic]

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did the whole left-hand-side filtering stuff for that boost converter come from? It seems somewhat pointless to add that sort of filtering there; you're probably not even using the filtered voltage for anything other than feeding the boost converter (or so it seems from the schematic), and those generally wouldn't care much about a "dirty" straight-from battery supply (of course with the adequate bypass caps); or so I would have thought. This just seems like an overkill to me there, it probably would've been better on the output side?

Comment: Note for readers: This question is a duplicate of [this one](https://www.diyaudio.com/forums/power-supplies/359026-portable-headphone-amp-power-supply-18v.html) just posted on the DIY Audio forum, so answers / progress / new information / relevant updates etc. might appear there.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat I used Texas Instruments [WEBENCH Power Designer Tool](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator) EDIT: added link

Comment: I see, there is an option that lets it add in an input EMI filter, which is what this is. Curiosity satisfied. :-)

Comment: Please post a specific question, make sure you tell people your cross posting across multiple sites if you do that https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site